# android add contact to phone

Tags: android, contacts

I am trying to add a contact to the phone itself.

i have the code working for adding it to say gmail or facebook account but what is the accounttype and name for phone.I did a list of all accounts and there is nothing like phone in there.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass `null` as the account's type and name, it will be stored in phone's address book. But some devices add such contacts to the first available account or to the address book if no accounts were added.

Comment: some phone will crash if "null" is being passed as the perimeter. Just wondering if there are any universal perimeter that will work for all phones.

Comment: I've never received a report from Android Market connected to this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

First, read up on ContentProvider: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Then, read this: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html

Comment: got that thats where i got the code for adding to a specific account like facebook